# Create a new user in an Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminal

Is it possible to create a new user to an old instance? The previous developer is using test-data@mydomain.com and we're just accessing it using a .pem file to access the terminal. If we access the terminal we use `ssh -i id_rsa.pem test-data@mydomain.com` but the problem is we don't have the password of the test-data@mydomain.com user. Is it possible to create a new user(test2-data@mydomain.com) via AWS console?

I've try to create a new .pem file and navigate the user channel but I can't find a way to create a new user.

Comment: There are no passwords. You should login using the keypair you have available, which hopefully has `sudo` permissions. You can then use it to create a new user.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein When I try to create a new user it is asking a password of test-data. But I don't know the password.

Comment: Are you using the `sudo` command? For example, `sudo adduser newuser`? Please edit your question and show the _exact_ command you are using and the output it displays.

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs into a Linux computer via SSH, the operating system will look in the user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. If it finds the a public keypair in that file that matches the supplied private keypair, then the user will be allowed to login.

Therefore, you should:

- Generate a new keypair
- Login to the instance
- Create a new user (see [Manage users on your Linux instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html))
- Add their public keypair to the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file

You will then be able to login to this new users using their username and private key.